# How would one round any integer to the next highest hundred in Java?

Tags: java, math, integer, rounding

To illustrate, I'd like to find out what the best way is to round the following integers:

(integer) -> (rounded value)

9 -> 100

200 -> 200

201 -> 300

1367 -> 1400

...so on and so forth... any suggestions on what would be the best way to accomplish this using Java?

Comment: which of the way will lead to the most memory efficent method .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Determine the modulus by 100

```
int k = 1234;
int mod = k % 100; //mod = 34
int difference = 100 - mod; //difference = 66
k += difference;
```

Straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

```
int d = num % 100;
num = num+100-d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int ceil100(int num) {
    return (num + 99) / 100 * 100;
}
```

Granted, not efficient, but still. The answers posted by others work too:

```
public static int ceil100(int num) {
    return num + 100 - num % 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Math#ceil()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil%28double%29)

```
int[] ints = {9, 200, 201, 1367, 90210};

int[] rounded = new int[5];
for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
    rounded[i] = (int) (Math.ceil(ints[i]/100f) * 100f);
}

// prints: [100, 200, 300, 1400, 90300]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rounded));
```